# Returning multidimensional array item in respective ASCII calendar location

Tags: java

I'm currently trying to add the functionality of viewing events on a calendar app that I have created. On launch, when a user types "ev" in the menu they have the ability to add an event with a month, day, and title, all of this is then added to the respective location on a multidimensional array of [12][monthlength]. Once they add an event to the array, when that certain month is displayed, the box that the event is on should be showing the title of the event, this last bit is where I'm getting stuck.

here's the array that data is being added to via user input (ev button):

```
public static Object[][] EVENTS = new Object[13][31];
```

representing 12 months with 31 days in each.

printing out the array looks something like this:

```
[[null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null], [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null], [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null], [null, EVENT, TITLE, null, NOTHER, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null], [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null], [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null], [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null], [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null], [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null], [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null], [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null], [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null], [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]]
```

while this does look like a mess, if you look at the third subarray you can see example data that was added via user input.

Finally trying to display this data onto the calendar is where things are getting complicated. Heres my code:

```
public static void drawRow(int week, int days, boolean firstWeek, int startDay, int month) {

        header(SIZE * 7);

        // this is for the firstt row of each row. includes day
        // draws each box for week length
        // if current loop count < start day, do an empty box
        //
        if (firstWeek == true) {
            // deals with height, days passed = length
            for (int i = 1; i <= SIZE / 2; i++) {
                if (startDay != 1) {
                    System.out.print("|");
                }

                spaceRow(startDay - 1, true, startDay, month, week);
                if (i == 1) {
                    numRow(week, days - startDay + 1, true);
                    System.out.print("|");
                } else {
                    spaceRow(days - startDay, true, startDay, month, week);

                    for (int last = 1; last <= SIZE - 1; last++) {
                        System.out.print(" ");
                    }
                    System.out.print("|");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }

        } else {

            numRow(week, days, false);

            System.out.println("|");
            // this is for the rest (without numbers)
            // height of each box
            for (int height = 1; height <= SIZE / 2 - 1; height++) {
                spaceRow(days, false, startDay, month, week);
            }
        }

    }

    public static void numRow(int week, int days, boolean first) {
        for (int col = 1; col <= days; col++) {
            if (first == true && col == 1) {
                System.out.print("");
            } else {
                System.out.print("|");
            }
            // get length of current days number
            String weekStr = String.valueOf(week);
            int length = weekStr.length();

            if (week <= 31) {

                System.out.print(week++);

            } else {
                System.out.print("  ");
            }

            for (int space = 1; space <= SIZE - length - 1; space++) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void spaceRow(int days, boolean first, int startDay, int mnth, int week) {
        //
        // makes each row (full length)

        for (int col2 = 1; col2 <= days; col2++) {
            // use week -1 to get correct day
            week++;
            if (first == true && col2 == 1) {

            } else {
                System.out.print("|");
            }
            //
            if (EVENTS[mnth][week - 1] != null) {
                System.out.print("x");
            } else {
                for (int space = 1; space <= SIZE - 1; space++) {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
            }

        }
        if (startDay == 7) {
            System.out.print("|");
        } else {
            System.out.print("|");
        }
        // if its the last row being drawn (when first ==true), dont go to the next row

        if (first == false) {
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    // division between weeks (=====)
    public static void header(int sz) {
        for (int top = 1; top <= sz; top++) {
            System.out.print("=");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

there is more code than this but I think this is enough to get an idea of what is happening. If you look about 3/4th of the way down, you can see "if (EVENTS[mnth][week - 1]" this is where im trying to hold the logic for deciding if an event should be placed in the empty space or not. ("x") was just for testing purposes but right now im getting an index out of range error.

Heres the calendar for some more context:

```
   __//
  /.__.\
  \ \/ /
`_/    \
 \-     )
  \____/ 
   | |         /
======================================================================
        \    \           \
                                  11 

 SUN       MON       TUE       WED       THU       FRI       SAT
======================================================================
|         |         |         |         |         |1        |2        |
|         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
|         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
|         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
|         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
======================================================================
|3        |4        |5        |6        |7        |8        |9        |
|         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
|         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
|         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
|         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
======================================================================
|10       |11       |12       |13       |14       |15       |16       |
|         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
|         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
|         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
|         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
======================================================================
|17       |18       |19       |20       |21       |22       |23       |
|         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
|         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
|         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
|         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
======================================================================
|24       |25       |26       |27       |28       |29       |30       |
|         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
|         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
|         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
|         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
======================================================================
Month: 11
Day: 2

Please type a command
'e' to enter a date and display the correspoding calendar 
't' to get todays date and display todays calendar
'n' to display the next month
'p' to display the previous month
'd' to exit the program
'ev' to add an event
```

Im aware this is kind of a messy question but any input or tips is appreciated. If you need more information ill be quick to reply. Thank you!

Comment: seems like building 12 arrays of "month" classes would be less confusing.  So the extra dimensions are in each class.  Maybe a hashmap for day/event in each.

Comment: Before progressing further, your model only supports 1 event per day. I would recommend you change to use a `Map<MonthDay, List<Event>>` instead of using a jagged array, where [`MonthDay`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/MonthDay.html) is the one from the Java 8 Time API. Changing how events are stored changes to logic for looking up events, so the problem you have might end up getting fixed when you refactor the code, and the result is a lot more flexible, so I'd suggest making this change now, rather than trying to fix what you currently have.

Comment: That solution sounds great but this is for a school project where we are only allowed to use the content we have learned so far, that content being multidimensional arrays. It is also only required that 1 event be displayed per day. I know this is not the best method but its what we are learning right now.

Comment: ahh... first I would suggest initializing the array.  Maybe set everything to "-1".  That way you don't have a bunch of nulls...  also, was this "new Object[13][31];" a typo in your post?  Seems like that should be 12 not 13.  The rest you'll figure out with debugging.